# What are these parts? Building Tip: Traffic Light Lego Creator

Tags: part-identification, piece-information, creator

[image]This look like a sturdy well designed set of traffic lights by LEGO. The constructing video links are below.

Unfortunately LEGO didn't provide the part details. I am no expert, can anyone help?

On the image I've put numbers next to unique parts. If you only know a few all good, we can collate them into a final list.

https://www.lego.com/en-us/kids/videos/creator/building-tip-traffic-light-252f2b716b40469a86f8688e5c8cad91

https://www.lego.com/en-us/kids/videos/creator-252f2b716b40469a86f8688e5c8cad91

Answer (score 8):

01 - [*Part #6003 - Plate, Round Corner 6 x 6.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6003&name=Plate,%20Round%20Corner%206%20x%206&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=85)

- [Color] Dark Bluish Grey.

02 - [*Part #3795 - Plate 2 x 6.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3795&name=Plate%202%20x%206&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=C&C=85)

- [Color] Dark Bluish Grey.

03 - [*Part #3700 Technic, Brick 1 x 2 with Hole.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3700&name=Technic,%20Brick%201%20x%202%20with%20Hole&category=%5BTechnic,%20Brick%5D#T=C&C=11)

- [Color] Black.

04 - [*Part #60897 - Plate, Modified 1 x 1 with Clip Vertical - Type 4 (thick open O clip).*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4085d&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%201%20with%20Clip%20Vertical%20-%20Type%204%20(thick%20open%20O%20clip)&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C&C=11)

- [Color] Black.

05 - [*Part #3024 - Plate 1 x 1.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3024&name=Plate%201%20x%201&category=%5BPlate%5D#T=C&C=11)

- [Color] Black.

06 - [*Part # 98138 - Tile, Round 1 x 1.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=98138&name=Tile,%20Round%201%20x%201&category=%5BTile,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=19)

- [Colors] Trans-Red, Trans-Yellow, and Trans-Green.

07 - [*Part #3069b - Tile 1 x 2 with Groove.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?id=17084#T=C)

- [Color] Black.

08 - [*Part #2431 - Tile 1 x 4.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=2431&name=Tile%201%20x%204&category=%5BTile%5D#T=C&C=86)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

09 - [*Part #14418 - Plate, Modified 1 x 2 with Small Towball Socket on End.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=14418&name=Plate,%20Modified%201%20x%202%20with%20Small%20Towball%20Socket%20on%20End&category=%5BPlate,%20Modified%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

10 - [*Part #60474 - Plate, Round 4 x 4 with Hole.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60474&name=Plate,%20Round%204%20x%204%20with%20Hole&category=%5BPlate,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=86)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

11 - [*Part #3941 - Brick, Round 2 x 2 with Axle Hole.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=3941&name=Brick,%20Round%202%20x%202%20with%20Axle%20Hole&category=%5BBrick,%20Round%5D#T=C&C=86)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

12 - [*Part #32062 - Technic, Axle 2 Notched.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32062&name=Technic,%20Axle%202%20Notched&category=%5BTechnic,%20Axle%5D#T=C&C=5)

- [Color] Red.

13 - [*Part #6628 - Technic, Pin with Friction Ridges Lengthwise and Towball.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6628&name=Technic,%20Pin%20with%20Friction%20Ridges%20Lengthwise%20and%20Towball&category=%5BTechnic,%20Pin%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Black.

14 - [Part #4519 - Technic, Axle 3.](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4519&name=Technic,%20Axle%203&category=%5BTechnic,%20Axle%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

15 - [*Part #32073 - Technic, Axle 5.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32073&name=Technic,%20Axle%205&category=%5BTechnic,%20Axle%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

16 - [*Part #60485 - Technic, Axle 9.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=60485&name=Technic,%20Axle%209&category=%5BTechnic,%20Axle%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

17 - [*Part #32034 - Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Angled #2 - 180 degrees.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32034&name=Technic,%20Axle%20and%20Pin%20Connector%20Angled%20#T=C&C=86)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

18 - [*Part #32014 - Technic, Axle and Pin Connector Angled #6 - 90 degrees.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32014&name=Technic,%20Axle%20and%20Pin%20Connector%20Angled%20#T=C&C=86)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

19 - [*Part #60187 - Hose, Rigid 3mm D. 4L / 3.2cm.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=75c04&name=Hose,%20Rigid%203mm%20D.%20%204L%20/%203.2cm&category=%5BHose,%20Rigid%203mm%20D.%5D#T=C&C=86)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

20 - [*Part #4274 - Technic, Pin 1/2.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4274&name=Technic,%20Pin%201/2&category=%5BTechnic,%20Pin%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

21 - [*Part #32039 - Technic, Axle Connector with Axle Hole.*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=32039&name=Technic,%20Axle%20Connector%20with%20Axle%20Hole&category=%5BTechnic,%20Connector%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

22 - [*Part #59443 - Technic, Axle Connector 2L (Smooth with x Hole + Orientation).*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=6538c&name=Technic,%20Axle%20Connector%202L%20(Smooth%20with%20x%20Hole%20%20%20Orientation)&category=%5BTechnic,%20Connector%5D#T=C)

- [Color] Light Bluish Grey.

**NEW!**
[image]

***FAST'N'Fuss-less*** download option:

If anyone is planning to purchase said pieces, I've amassed a LXF file with all the parts.

Just *[download the file](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1JtREB2nzdZCFcyua70sjFJd3TULH38ph)* to your system, go to [*Bricklink.com*](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/wanted/upload.page), create a new wanted list, and from there drag and drop this file.

**BOOM!** You're ready to buy your pieces.

[image]

Comment: You smashed it one! Thank you so much

Comment: You made it even easier thank you again!